# UINavigationBar not showing up in modal view

Tags: iphone, uistoryboard

I have a storyboard as seen in this picture:
[image]

From a table view cell, I modally present a new view controller which is a subclass of UITableViewController.  In the scene on the RHS I have a UINavigationBar.  But when my view is presented, it does not have it.  Why is that?  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll need to embed your subclass of UITableViewController that you want presented modally inside of a UINavigationController.

To do this, click the view you want presented modally in your Storyboard, then go to Editor>Embed In>Navigation Controller.